# Count a specific value for many columns

Tags: t-sql, count

I want to get an output that gives me the count of '0's of each column. For one column I get it by

```
select COUNT(*) from Q_Basis
where V1 = '0'
```

where the names of the relevant columns are v1, v2, ..., v60.

I have found out that I can do counts over all columns with

```
select count(*), *
```

but that does not help in my case since I still have to specify all columnnames in the where clause.

Any idea how I can acomplish this without hardcoding this in the where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN V1 = '0' THEN 1 END) As NumOfV1Zeros,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN V2 = '0' THEN 1 END) As NumOfV2Zeros,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN V3 = '0' THEN 1 END) As NumOfV3Zeros
FROM Q_Basis
WHERE '0' IN(V1, V2, V3) -- Don't count records that doesn't interest you...
```

You can't avoid specifying the column names individually, but if there are a lot of columns, you can dynamically create such a select statement using `infromation_schema.columns`.